# SQL UNION error - Selected columns do not match

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, inner-join, union

I'm trying to use a `SQL UNION` query to populate my `DataGridView`.

The 3 tables I'm trying to join are;

- **Customers** - Contains basic customer information (PK: **Customer_Code**)
- **Customer_Addresses** - Contains contact information (Telephone, fax, address etc) (PK: **Cust_Code**)
- **Delivery_Addresses** - The same as Customer_Addresses, but for delivery locations (PK: **Cust_Code**)

I'm trying to display in my `DataGridView` some data from each table. I want to be able to show, on each row, the data from each table, and join it using the Primary Keys I mentioned above.

So far, I have tried joining using an `INNER JOIN` and a `UNION JOIN`. However, an `INNER JOIN` didn't allow me to select only some columns from both tables, whereas a `UNION JOIN` gave me the following error;

> The number of columns in the two selected tables or queries of a union query do not match.

This is my code, what am I doing wrong?

```
ElseIf type = "Customer" Then
 sql = "SELECT [Customer_Code], [Customer_Name], [Customer_Category], " & _
       "[Average_Payment_Terms], [Notes], [Aq_Date], [salesRep], [hoEmail], [webpage] " & _
       "FROM Customers " & _
       "UNION SELECT [Contact_Code], [Contact_Type], [Contact_Name], [Add1], [Add2], " & _
       "[Add3], [Add4], [Add5], [Postcode], [Country], [Telephone], [Fax], " & _
       "[Email], [Mobile_Phone] FROM [Customer_Addresses]"

 Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
 Dim ds As New DataSet
 Dim dt As New DataTable

 da.Fill(ds) ' This is the line that the error occurs on
 dt = ds.Tables(0).Copy()
```

**EDT**

I've tried using a `JOIN` again and used the following;

```
ElseIf type = "Customers" Then
   sql = "SELECT Customer_Addresses.Cust_Code, Customers.Customer_Name, " & _
          "Customers.Customer_Category, Customers.Average_Payment_Terms, Customers.Notes, " & _
          "Customers.Aq_Date, Customers.salesRep, Customers.hoEmail, Customers.webpage, " & _
          "Customer_Addresses.Contact_Code, Customer_Addresses.Contact_Name, " & _
          "Customer_Addresses.Contact_Type, Customer_Addresses.Add1, Customer_Addresses.Add2, " & _
          "Customer_Addresses.Add3, Customer_Addresses.Add4, Customer_Addresses.Add5, " & _
          "Customer_Addresses.Postcode, Customer_Addresses.Country, Customer_Addresses.Telephone, " & _
          "Customer_Addresses.Fax, Customer_Addresses.Email, Customer_Addresses.Mobile_Phone " & _
          "FROM Customers AS c INNER JOIN Customer_Addresses AS a ON c.Customer_Code = a.Cust_Code"

   Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
   Dim ds As New DataSet
   Dim dt As New DataTable

   da.Fill(ds)
   dt = ds.Tables(0).Copy()

   dgvExport.DataSource = dt
```

Which results in the following error;

> No value given for one or more required parameters

Comment: I have no idea what a `UNION JOIN` is, or even if you should be using a `UNION` here, but the error is being caused by the number/types of the columns selected from the two tables in the union are not the same.  Think of stacking two tables on top of each other; if the number of columns or types aren't the same, the union won't work.

Comment: as @TimBiegeleisen points out, `UNION` fails for the reason described in the error message. What makes you think that you can't select only some columns from each table when doing a `JOIN`?

Comment: @Blackwood I had a look online and couldn't find a way of doing so... All of the examples seemed to only allow selection of rows from table1, for example, and searching for how to select from both is what brought me to the `UNION` idea

Comment: What SQL platform are you using? `UNION` is definitely the wrong approach.

Comment: @rheitzman I'm using MS-Access

Comment: Get the query working in Access first, then switch to SQL View for the query to retrieve the SQL query.

Comment: @rheitzman see the query in my edit. I put it into Access, but it asks me for a value for each of the fields I'm trying to select?

Comment: Start from a fresh query and use the query designer to build the SQL. If it prompting for names the designer thinks the fields are parameters since they don't match any existing field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should be using an `INNER JOIN` for this.

Secondly, to use an inner join, you need to make sure that the keys you wish to join on have a relationship between them in Access. When making a new query, and adding the two tables (In Access) to the query, it will tell you there is no relationship between them. Pressing the 'OK' button will take you to the relationships designer screen.

Select from your `Customers` table the `Primary Key` (`Customer_Code`), and drag it across to the matching key in the other 2 tables (`Cust_Code`). This will allow the database to join the keys together, instead of asking for parameter values.

The query itself should then look like this;

```
sql = "SELECT [Customer_Addresses].[Cust_Code], " & _
   "[Customer_Addresses].[Contact_Code], [Customer_Addresses].[Contact_Name], " & _
   "[Customer_Addresses].[Contact_Type], [Customer_Addresses].[Add1], " & _
   "[Customer_Addresses].[Add2], [Customer_Addresses].[Add3], " & _
   "[Customer_Addresses].[Add4], [Customer_Addresses].[Add5], " & _
   "[Customer_Addresses].[Postcode], [Customer_Addresses].[Country]," & _
   "[Customer_Addresses].[Telephone], [Customer_Addresses].[Fax], " & _
   "[Customer_Addresses].[Email], [Customer_Addresses].[Mobile_Phone], " & _
   "[Customers].[Customer_Code], [Customers].[Customer_Category], " & _
   "[Customers].[Average_Payment_Terms], [Customers].[Customer_Name], [Customers].[Notes], " & _
   "[Customers].[Aq_Date], [Customers].[salesRep], " & _
   "[Customers].[hoEmail], [Customers].[webpage] FROM Customers " & _
   "INNER JOIN Customer_Addresses ON [Customers].[Customer_Code] =[Customer_Addresses].[Cust_Code]"
```

Obviously this is just for two tables, but once you join the `Primary Key` up to `Delivery_Addresses.Cust_Code` then it will include this table too.

Another thing to note is that if you have 100 customers, let's say, and each has 1 address in `Customer_Addresses`, but only 5 customers have an address in `Delivery_Addresses`, it will only show the 5 customers with a delivery address. It will show data from all 3 tables, but only records where data for that customer exists in all tables.

Maybe storing addresses in just one table is the better way to do it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't have relationships, that explains it. There's a lot of information here, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Use JOIN instead:

```
sql = "SELECT C.Customer_Code, C.Customer_Name, C.Customer_Category, " & _
   "C.Average_Payment_Terms, C.Notes, C.Aq_Date, C.salesRep, C.hoEmail, C.webpage, A.Contact_Code, A.Contact_Type, A.Contact_Name, A.Add1, A.Add2, " & _
   "A.Add3, A.Add4, A.Add5, A.Postcode, A.Country, A.Telephone, A.Fax, " & _
   "A.Email, A.Mobile_Phone FROM Customers C INNER JOIN Customer_Addresses A ON C.Customer_Code=A.Cust_Code "
```

Comment: This is not valid vb